# Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/objectSpread' after update meteor to 1.6.1.1

Tags: meteor, npm, babeljs

i updated my meteor project to  Meteor 1.6.1.1. and i got this error message

```
  => Exited with code: 1
W20180403-15:33:17.531(2)? (STDERR) E:\Personnal folders\quicktext5\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:475
W20180403-15:33:17.534(2)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20180403-15:33:17.535(2)? (STDERR)    ^
W20180403-15:33:17.539(2)? (STDERR)
W20180403-15:33:17.540(2)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/objectSpread'
W20180403-15:33:17.541(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
W20180403-15:33:17.543(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
W20180403-15:33:17.547(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.require (E:\Personnal folders\quicktext5\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:288:32)
W20180403-15:33:17.548(2)? (STDERR)     at makeInstallerOptions.fallback (packages\modules-runtime.js:651:18)
W20180403-15:33:17.548(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:244:16)
W20180403-15:33:17.549(2)? (STDERR)     at livedata_connection.js (E:\Personnal folders\quicktext5\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages\ddp-client.js:149:45)
W20180403-15:33:17.550(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20180403-15:33:17.550(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180403-15:33:17.551(2)? (STDERR)     at namespace.js (packages/ddp-client/common/namespace.js:1:300)
W20180403-15:33:17.556(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtime.js:343:9)
```

i tried to delete the **node_modules folder** and run `npm install` .
I also tried to install  `meteor npm install --save babel-runtime`
but still got the same Error
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well since the meteor-babel npm package has been updated to version 7.0.0-beta.44, which may require updating any custom Babel plugins I have enabled in a .babelrc file, I tried to running the following command to update @babel/runtime:

```
meteor npm install @babel/runtime@latest
```

Thanks to **@robfallows** who answered my question in **Meteor forums**
https://forums.meteor.com/t/cannot-find-module-babel-runtime-helpers-builtin-objectspread-after-update-meteor-to-1-6-1-1/43034

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is still having the same problem, if you are not using meteor1.7.x then the latest version of babel/runtime might not fix the error for you as it didn't fix for me, what worked however was to use.

`meteor npm install babel/runtime@7.0.0-beta.55`

The best option would be however to update to the latest version of Meteor but if you aren't ready use the beta version above it will fix the error.

Answer (score 2):

Updated to Meteor 1.7 which identified the error, said to do this:

```
meteor npm install --save-exact @babel/runtime@7.0.0-beta.55
```

Back online!